# Contiki OS CC2538: Reducing current / power consumption

Tags: contiki

I am trying to drive down the current consumption of the contiki os running on the CC2538 development kit.

I would like to operate the device from a CR2032 with a run life of 2 years. To achieve this I would need an average current less than 100uA.

However when I run the following at 3V, I get the following results:

- contiki/examples/hello-world = 0.4mA - 2mA
- contiki/examples/er-rest-example/er-example-client = 27mA
- contiki/examples/er-rest-example/er-example-server = 27mA
- thingsquare websocket example = 4mA

I have also designed my own target platform based on the cc2538 and get similar results.

I have read the guide at https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/648d3576a081b84edd33da05a3a973e209835723/platform/cc2538dk/README.md
and have ensured that in the contiki-conf.h file:
- LPM_CONF_ENABLE 1 
- LPM_CONF_MAX_PM 2

Can anyone give me some pointers as to how I can get the current down. It would be most appreciated.

Regards,
Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you measure the current?

You have to be aware that using a basic ampere meter to measure the current consumption of contiki-os wouldn't give you relevant results. The system is turning on/off the radio at a relative high rate (8Hz by default) in order to perform the CCA. This might not be very easy to catch for an ampere meter.

To have an idea of the current consumption when the device is in deep sleep (and then make calculation to determine the averaged current consumption), I'd rather put the device in the PM state before the program reach the infinite while loop. I used the following code to do that:

```c
lpm_enter();
REG(SYS_CTRL_PMCTL) = SYS_CTRL_PMCTL_PM2;
do { asm("wfi"::); } while(0);
leds_on(LEDS_RED); // should not reach here
while(1){ 
 ...
```

On the CC2538, the CCA check consumes about 10-15mA and last approximately 2ms. When the radio transmit a packet, it consume 25mA. Have a look at this post: [Contiki UDP packet transmission duration with CC2538](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179093/contiki-udp-packet-transmission-duration-with-cc2538/26184677).

Furthermore, to save a little more current, turn off the serial com:

```
#define CC2538_CONF_QUIET 1
```

Are you using the SmartRF board? If you want to make proper current measurement with this board, you have to remove every jumpers: P486, P487, P411 and P408. Keep only the jumpers of BTN_SEL and the RESET signals.

Comment: I try your suggestion whiched forced the untit into PM2 mode.

Comment: I try your suggestion which forced the into PM2 mode. Hello World = ~150uA. Discovered that in LPM,the CC2538 sets each IO as inputs with pullups. In ended up that one of my IO was tied to 0V. After correcting this problem the current reduced to 1.4uA. Thankyou for your suggestions to help me answer the current problem.